# Youtube Data Api v3

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I'm building an app in which I want to access the title of a particular video and it's thumbnail in my app. I want to use the Youtube Data Api v3 to get the title and thumbnail of a video through it's URL. But I have no idea how to implement this in an android app to access these two things in my app. How can I use the Youtube Data Api v3? Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your Youtube Data API v3 key then use [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint this way: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=YOUR_VIDEO_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY then in the answer the fields `title`and `thumbnails` are what you are looking for.